# Inform7 Can't Re-enter Containers

Tags: containers, inform7

I'm currently having a small problem with getting containers to work properly in inform7. I've created a bed, which is marked as an enterable container. When the scene begins, the player is started out in the bed, and that appears to work ok. You can leave the container just fine. BUT, you can't re-enter the container. If I try to enter/get in/go inside the bed I get a message saying "you can't go that way" and I don't understand why. I'm quite new so there's probably something super simple that I'm missing here. Any ideas? Thanks so much!

Here's my code:

```
A Warm Cabin is a room. "A one room cabin with a fireplace on the south wall. There's a single window, frosted over from the cold."

Coming to is a scene. Coming to begins when Unconscious ends.

When coming to begins:
    move the player to the double bed;
    try waking up;
    continue the action.

The Double Bed is a container. The double bed is in a warm cabin. The double bed is enterable and fixed in place. The description of the double bed is "A double bed strewn with soft, botanically-embroidered quilts and over-fluffed pillows. . . It's quite cozy."

Instead of entering the double bed: try going inside.
```

Comment: Just remove the last line. It's blocking the entering action.